# Beamer, Babel and Tikz conflict

Tags: beamer, babel, tikz-arrows

I am preparing lecture notes in Turkish,
and I have a digram for mathematical modelling procedure.
But I **cannot** produce a good output for the following code.
When I remove the first three *packages*, I get my desired output.
However, I need to have keep them in my document.
Would you help me in this direction?

```
\documentclass[10pt,notheorems]{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[turkish]{babel}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes,arrows}

\hypersetup{bookmarksdepth=4,bookmarksnumbered=true,bookmarksopen=true}

\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usecolortheme{seahorse}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{}{}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (rwp) [draw,fill=blue!20,text centered,minimum height=2em,rounded corners] {Ger\c{c}ek ya\c{s}am problemi};
    \node (mm) [right=2cm of rwp,draw,fill=purple!20,text centered,minimum height=2em,rounded corners] {Matematiksel model};
    \node (mc) [below=2cm of mm,draw,fill=green!20,text centered,minimum height=2em,rounded corners] {Matematiksel \c{c}{\i}kar{\i}m};
    \node (rwq) [below=2cm of rwp,draw,fill=red!20,text centered,minimum height=2em,rounded corners] {Ger\c{c}ek ya\c{s}am tahminleri};
    \path [draw,->] (rwp.east) -- node [above] {Form\"{u}lasyon} (mm.west);
    \path [draw,->] (mm.south) -- node [right] {\c{C}\"{o}z\"{u}m} (mc.north);
    \path [draw,->] (mc.west) -- node [below] {Yorum} (rwq.east);
    \path [draw,->] (rwq.north) -- node [left] {Kontrol} (rwp.south);
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \caption{Modelleme s\"{u}reci}\label{s2ss2fig1}
\end{figure}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Babel defines various shorthands to simplify the input of special characters, which is very handy to input letters, but sometimes this causes conflicts with others packages. Luckily `tikz` has the library `\usetikzlibrary{babel}` that solves the problem.

```
\documentclass[10pt,notheorems]{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[turkish]{babel}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes,arrows}

\usetikzlibrary{babel}

\hypersetup{bookmarksdepth=4,bookmarksnumbered=true,bookmarksopen=true}

\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usecolortheme{seahorse}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{}{}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (rwp) [draw,fill=blue!20,text centered,minimum height=2em,rounded corners] {Ger\c{c}ek ya\c{s}am problemi};
    \node (mm) [right=2cm of rwp,draw,fill=purple!20,text centered,minimum height=2em,rounded corners] {Matematiksel model};
    \node (mc) [below=2cm of mm,draw,fill=green!20,text centered,minimum height=2em,rounded corners] {Matematiksel \c{c}{\i}kar{\i}m};
    \node (rwq) [below=2cm of rwp,draw,fill=red!20,text centered,minimum height=2em,rounded corners] {Ger\c{c}ek ya\c{s}am tahminleri};
    \path [draw,->] (rwp.east) -- node [above] {Form\"{u}lasyon} (mm.west);
    \path [draw,->] (mm.south) -- node [right] {\c{C}\"{o}z\"{u}m} (mc.north);
    \path [draw,->] (mc.west) -- node [below] {Yorum} (rwq.east);
    \path [draw,->] (rwq.north) -- node [left] {Kontrol} (rwp.south);
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \caption{Modelleme s\"{u}reci}\label{s2ss2fig1}
\end{figure}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]